# Laravel 5.2 bind controllers to abstract route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am upgrading application written in Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.2.
I have long namespaces for my controllers and want to shorten them.

For example:

**CustomServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Shortname\Somecontroller', 'Really\Really\Long\Name\Somecontroller');
}
```

**routes.php**

```
$router->get('someroute', ['uses' => 'Shortname\Somecontroller@someFunction']);
```

was possible inside custom service provider and works in Laravel 4.2 and Larave 5.1. After I've started migrating to Laravel 5.2 it stopped working.

Closest I came to the solution was this issue report: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14920 but it doesn't work either.

This works for example:

**routes_alternative.php**

```
$router->get('someroute', ['uses' => 'Really\Really\Long\Name\Somecontroller@someFunction']);
```

I've tried `Really\Really\Long\Name\Somecontroller::class` and moving everything to `RouteServiceProvider`. I've also tried `artisan route:clear`,`artisan cache:clear`, `artisan dump-autoload`, `artisan clear-compiled` and all sorts of other composer and artisan shenanigans.

All actions result in exception:

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
>   Class Shortname\Somecontroller does not exist

Does someone have similar expiriences and was able to solve it?

Comment: Does this helps? `Somecontroller::class` instead of `'Really\Really\Long\Name\Somecontroller'`.

Comment: no, I've tried that already. and ::class is the same as writing 'Really\Really\Long\Name\Somecontroller'

Comment: But you can import them with `use`.

Comment: but it still doesn't work. I think that removing ControllerServiceProvider in L5.2 had something to do with it but I can't find the correct solution.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain better what's troubling me